# What is wrong with this Java code for a RMI JMX connection?

Tags: java, groovy, rmi, jmx

What is wrong with this Java code for a RMI JMX connection?   I am clearly not trying to connect to localhost but the error implies that I am.   On the remote server, I enabled JMX options on port 1099 (no authentication).

Here is my groovy script:

```
import javax.management.remote.*;    
JMXServiceURL u = 
 new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://10.222.244.185:9999/jndi/rmi://10.222.244.185:1099/jmxrmi");    
JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(u);
```

And here is the error I get:

```
C:\Temp>groovy jmx.gv
Caught: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Conn
ection refused to host: 10.222.244.185; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection r
efused to host: 10.222.244.185; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
        at jmx.run(jmx.gv:5)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.222.244.185; nested except
ion is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.222.244.185; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Sorry guys.  I just discovered that the remote JVM was running on OpenJDK while the VisualVM I was using was on Oracle Hotspot.  This must have been the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't have been. More likely it wasn't running at all.

Comment: is ping and telnet working to host:ports ? (just to rule out network problems)

Answer (score 1):

This is the famous java.rmi.server.hostname problem. Usually caused by /etc/hosts misconfiguration in some Linux distributions. 127.0.0.1 should map to localhost, and your real hostname should map to your real IP address. See item A.1 in the RMI FAQ for another solution.

**EDIT:** Now that you've edited the IP addresses in your question, it is more probable that the JMX service you are looking up simply isn't running at that IP address.

Comment: It seems OP using windows machine c:\>Temp?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your code trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` instead of remote

```
Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
```

I suspect the code you are executing is different from the code you have in question. Make sure what ever the code you have in question is being executed.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see how that is possible.  My configured URL (above) clearly is connecting to the 10. subnet.

Comment: Are you testing this from your local or deploying some where?

Comment: I changed my question a little bit.  Can you re-evaluate?  Maybe its too hard to ask someone else because this type of environment could have many factors contributing to the problem?

Comment: Have you verified any firewalls running? I would do this, first use JConsole and make sure you are able to connect using that URL.

Comment: If you are not on windows, its worth to check EJP answer first before doing anything.

Comment: It's worth checking anyway, especially the RMI FAQ item.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of configurtion issue where you have to explicitly mention how are you going to access the stubs. Try setting jmxremote options through JVM args. Following options might resolve your issue. I tried same for my own project.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8091
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8091
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```